# Is it possible to get the model name of NFC chip in an android phone?

Tags: android, sdk, hardware, nfc

There are many app which says the processor name or the sensors models. Is there methods in android SDK to get the name of the NFC chip ? I don't find anything in android.nfc or android.nfc.tech
Indeed, some tags aren't detected by some chips.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such method in the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Samsung Galaxy S.

When I list `/dev` there is an entry called "pn544" with userid/grouip "nfc".

[PN544](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/brochure/75017000.pdf) is also the product name of a popular NFC controller by NXP...

Comment: Thanks but I want the type of the NFC chips, not the card.

Comment: Right. have you tried it with Linux console commands? They might expose a lot of info about the available hardware.

Comment: Good idea but I have not found command to read this information without a root access...

Comment: I have a Samsung Galaxy S. When I list /dev there is an entry called "pn544" with userid/grouip "nfc". PN544 is also the product name of a popular NFC controller by NXP...

Comment: Yes ! me too. Now i need to find a phone with another chips to see if there is an entry like this.  THANKS !

Comment: Thanks, I did see the `pn544` in the console. This `ls -l /dev` interrogation is ad-hoc. For example, doing the same against bluetooth did not reveal any identifiable string.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible. Check this
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

Comment: I am interested in the presence of an NXP controller chip. The `ls -l /dev | grep nfc` showed a clue via the `pn544` NXP chip. But this method is not a documented API. And neither is it documented in an Android API to get this low level detail piece of information.